Schauder bases in inductive limits
Assume $X_n$ is a family of nested Banach spaces (i.e. $X_n\subset X_m$ whenever $m>n$ and
the inclusion map is continuous) and denote by $X$ the inductive limit $\lim X_n$. Assume moreover that $X$ has an absolute Schauder basis $\{(x_n,f_n)\}$
(where the $x_n$ are the elements of the basis and $f_n$ are the associated functionals) and that
all the basis elements are contained in $X_1$. It is well known that,
if the limit is strict, then $\{(x_n,f_n)\}$ is an absolute Schauder basis in each of the $X_n$.
My question is: what can we deduce (if anything) about the Schauder-like properties of $\{(x_n,f_n)\}$ in $X_1$, if we do not assume the limit to be strict?
I can prove that it does not have to be an absolute basis (it suffices to find an LB space $X$ with an absolute basis such that $X_1$ is not isomorphic to $\ell_1$), but this leaves open the possibility of it being a Schauder basis.

The following article could be helpful: Floret, K.
Bases in sequentially retractive limit-spaces. Studia Math. 38 (1970), 221–226.

@Jochen That is indeed rather helpful, thank you!
